# jQuery how do i access the url i just used in a callback function?

Tags: jquery

So I have a jQuery callback for a load function like so:

```
$(".editStoryLink").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().siblings(".storyTitleDesc")
        .load($(this).attr("href"), function(data) {
            alert("the url that was just used above!");
        });
    return false;
});
```

How would I access the URL that I just used?

Answer (score 3):

Make its backup before running `load` request:

```
$(".editStoryLink").click(function() {
    var url = this.href;
    $(this).parent().siblings(".storyTitleDesc").load(url, function(data) {
        alert(url);
    });
    return false;
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/MhSAH/